# Keyboard on DialogFragment in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment

In my application, when a button is clicked, dialogfragment shows up, then soft keyboard is shown and then if I change orientation keyboard is always shown. But if I lunch application on landscape at first keyboard does not shows up. Any idea why keyboard does not show?

```
public class PlateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

static View view;
public static PlateDialogFragment newInstance(View v) {
    view=v;
    PlateDialogFragment f = new PlateDialogFragment();
    f.setCancelable(false);
    f.setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, STYLE_NO_TITLE);
    return f;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_plate, container, false);
    setRetainInstance(false);
    Button cancel = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.exit);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(cancelDialogListener);
    Button next = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(nextDialogListener);

    plate1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.plate1);
    plate1.setOnFocusChangeListener(plateFocusChanged);
    plate1.addTextChangedListener(plate1Watcher);
    plate2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.plate2);
    plate2.setOnFocusChangeListener(plateFocusChanged);
    plate2.addTextChangedListener(plate2Watcher);
    plate3 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.plate3);
    plate3.setOnFocusChangeListener(plateFocusChanged);
    plate3.addTextChangedListener(plate3Watcher);
    plate3.setOnEditorActionListener(plate3EditorActionListener);
    plate1.requestFocus();
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    Log.i("onDetach", "onDetach");
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(plate1.getWindowToken(), 0);
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this may be due to full-screen [so-called 'extracted'] IME mode for landscape -- since it would obscure your whole UI *[which would be counter-intuitive for the user]*, it's not being shown until user taps one of the inputs *[thus acknowledging they really want the IME to pop up and take whatever real estate it needs]*

As a possible way to cope with this, try setting

```
plate1.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

for eachi `EditText` or use the corresponding

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

attribute for `EditText`s in layout files.

Comment: Hm, then I'm out of ideas. I'll update if something comes to mind